# Cufon font isn't applied for link generated with JSF EL expression when use message bundling

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, cufon

I'm trying to use Cufon js lib. to display specific font on web page.
jQuery is used also.

```
<script language="javascript" src="resources/js/cufon-yui.js"/>
<script language="javascript" src="resources/js/Salaryman_400.font.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.replace('.menu-text');
</script>
```

if link text obtained with EL `#{m.decoys}`,which mean that it's value got from properties file in order to support i18n,that it doesn't work:

```
<h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/decoys.jsf" class="menu-text">
   <f:verbatim>#{m.decoys}</f:verbatim>
</h:outputLink>
```

after this text within `<a>` wasn't displayed at all.

here is i18n setting in faces-config,they work without Cufon:

```
<application>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>msg_ru</base-name>
            <var>m</var>
        </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

if link text is obtained with other EL, eg. `#{request.contextPath}` ,that it's OK:

```
<h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/decoys.jsf" class="menu-text">
   <f:verbatim>#{request.contextPath}</f:verbatim>
</h:outputLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such attribute "class" for h:outputLink.
You should use "styleClass":

```
<h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/decoys.jsf" styleClass="menu-text" id="cufId">
```

Comment: class attribute is applied also.Anyway,it doesn't work with styleClass too.